# How to resize Metro window?

Tags: c++, resize, windows-store-apps

How do I programatically make Metro windows fullscreen in 8.1 with C++?

I have tried this but it doesn't work and always returns false:

```
Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()->TryUnsnap();
```

Also, the docs say it's deprecated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible; it is always the user's choice through interaction with the Metro shell to view your application at the size they desire.  Your application cannot programmatically change that (otherwise you could implement a program that behaved maliciously).